# how to test select2 by geb

Tags: jquery, grails, testing, groovy, geb

I am trying to select option from the select2 dropDown list but i am not able to do so This is the code

```
enter code here

 <select id="addedLanguageId" class="input-large select2-me
 select2-offscreen"    name="language.id" style="width: 200px;"
 tabindex="-1"> <option value="">Select a language</option> <option
 value="1">Aboriginal Dialects</option> <option
 value="2">Afrikaans</option> <option value="3">Ainu</option> <option
 value="4">Akkadian</option> <option value="5">Albanian</option>
 </select>`
```

I have tried so many things like `$("form").language.id=["4"]` or added code in page like `selectLang{$('#language.id')}` and in test like `selectLang.value('20')`. I used other concepts like `selectLang{$('#language.id')}` and

```
dropdownSelectedText {selectLang.find('option', value:selectLang.value()).text()}
```

in page and done testing with:

```
when:
selectLang='Akkadian' 
then:
dropdownSelectedText=='Akkadian'
selectLang.value()=='Akkadian'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this. As my understanding it is not the select2 issue. I wrote selenium test below. And it is working for select and select2 both.

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/");
    WebElement select=driver.findElement(By.id("e1"));
    List<WebElement> options = select.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
    for(WebElement option : options){
        if(option.getText().equals("California")) {
            option.click();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: after looking at some of my geb tests, I am setting select2 values like this (using geb 0.9.2):

Define a selector for your form in a page object:

```
static content = {
    myForm { $("form") }
}
```

Then in your test, you can set the select2 value like this:

```
myForm."language.id" = "4"
```

Comment: it is not working sir In geb we can not provide command like this could you provide some other option

Comment: Hmm.. ok. Looking at one of my tests, I declare my form in my Page object like this: `myForm { $("form") }`. Then in my geb spec, I set the select2 value like this: `myForm."some.id" = "123"`. Could you try that?